# How to compute the radical ideal of parabolic subalgebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I try to solve the following question:

> Let $\mathfrak{g}\subset \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ be the subspace consisting of the matrices:
>   $$\mathfrak{g}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&D\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
>   where $A$ is a $k×k$ matrix, $B$ is a $k×(n−k)$ matrix, and $D$ is a $(n−k)×(n−k)$ matrix.
>
> Show that radical of $\mathfrak{g}$ consists of matrices of the form 
>   $$\mathfrak{h}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda \cdot I&B\\0&\mu \cdot I\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
>   and describe $\mathfrak{g}/ \mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{g})$.

---

I don't have any experience about computation of the radical ideal of a Lie algebra.

And all what I know is $\mathfrak{g}/ \mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple. But it provides no information for the explicit form of the matrices.

The definition of "solvable" is not natural for computing what the ideal looks like for me so far....

Comment: Hint: let $\mathfrak{h}$ be the given subspace. (a) show that $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal (b) show that $\mathfrak{h}$ is solvable (c) describe the quotient $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ and check that it's semisimple (d) conclude that $\mathfrak{h}$ is the radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description should probably be $\mathfrak{g} = \Big\{ \begin{pmatrix}  A & B \\ 0 & D \end{pmatrix} \Big\}.$

One way you might do this is through the equation $$\mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak{g}) = [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]^{\perp},$$ the orthogonal complement with respect to the Killing form. Here $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ consists of those matrices for which $A$ and $D$ are both traceless.

Comment: The Killing form is quite lengthy to compute, so this is certainly not the easiest approach

Comment: @YCor I thought it is the usual $\kappa(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} ((xy)_{ii} + (xy)_{jj} - x_{ii} y_{jj} - x_{jj} y_{ii})$ but now only summed over those $i,j$ in the three nonzero blocks? In particular for $y \in [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$, $\kappa(x,y)$ should be a multiple of $\mathrm{tr}(xy)$

Answer (score 1):

You can show 
$$\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}\cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,k)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$$

And $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$ is semisimple and its direct sum is semisimple.